# Visual Leak Detector not finding leaks VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks, visual-leak-detector

I can't seem to make VLD catch any memory leaks no matter what I tried. Any ideas why ?

Here snippet of the output too:

```
Visual Leak Detector Version 2.4RC2 installed. 
The thread 0x5748 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2c70 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3c98 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
No memory leaks detected.
Visual Leak Detector is now exiting.
The program '[24988] ConsoleApplication2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

```
#include <vld.h>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Car{
    public:
        Car() {}

        Car(string model,int year, string color) {
            this->model = model; this->color, this->year = year;
        }

        string getModel() {
            return this->model;
        }

        void setModel(string m) {
            this->model = model;
        }

        string getColor() {
            return this->color;
        }

        void setColor(string color) {
            this->color = color;
        }

        void paint()
        {
            setColor("white");
        }

    private:
        string model;
        int year;
        string color;
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
    Car c("bmw", 2000, "red");
    c.paint();
    cout << c.getColor().c_str();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        int *ptr = new int(10);

    Car *c2 = new Car("benz", 2010, "yellow");

    return 0;
 }
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's working under visual studio 2013 ultimate

You have to execute the program in a console mode (go to the debug directory of the project)

In the following, you will find a picture of the result, but the console displayed many leaks we can't see all of them here

I added the include and lib paths to the project setting

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\include
2. C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\lib\win32
3. C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\lib\win64

[image]

As you see there is 13 memory leaks.